# How old can Trolls get?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, aging

Trolls have an insane regenerative ability, being able to regain lost hitpoints in a flash and even regrow lost bodyparts.
My question: Does this have any effect on their lifespan? I understand that the average troll is unlikely to live a long and healthy life due to their tendency for combat, but presume a Troll that is either strong enough to win all these battles, or peaceful/lucky enough to never run into a fight. What is the maximum age a Troll could possibly (naturally) reach?

Answers from any official source, regardless of edition are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Trolls naturally live for about a hundred years

The *Dragon #301* article *Malignant Growth: The Ecology of the Troll* (part of *Dragon*'s long series of "*Ecology of ...*" articles exploring monster biology and behaviour in more detail) posits that trolls reach full maturity at about 10 years old and can live to be around 100. Their regeneration is not mentioned as influencing their natural longevity at all.

> The natural lifespan of trolls is approximately 100 years, and they reach maturity after just 10 years, although they can hunt and fend for themselves within a year after birth.

This isn't an upper bound, so it's unclear how long a particular troll could potentially live if it was extremely lucky. However, it seems reasonable to assume that, as with most creatures with lifespans in that ballpark, natural variance would put almost all trolls within a couple of decades either side of that 100-year average.

*Dragon #301* was published in 2002, making it a 3e-era source.

Answer (score 4):

### “The natural lifespan of trolls is approximately 100 years”

According to the article *Malignant Growth: The Ecology of the Troll* by Paul Leach, from *Dragon* Magazine #301 (p. 61) in November 2002:

> The natural lifespan of trolls is approximately 100 years

There is no mention of their regeneration affecting their lifespan.